# When clicking on RecyclerView Item, returns wrong information

Tags: java, android

#### Long post, thanks for taking the time to look through this

I have been struggling with this issue for a while now. I have an SQLiteDatabase which stores a shoe's brand name, name of shoe, and a byte image of the shoe. I was able to load all of the information to a recyclerview via a content provider. But it seems when I try and load the information to the details of each item in the recycler view, the details activity is filled with the wrong information, it returns a completely different entry other than the one I selected.

The solutions I've seen in many youtube videos have contained me creating ArrayLists to store the information, but I find that very hard to do using my SQLiteDatabase information.

Here are the classes I have...
My Closet.java class(with my getter methods)

```
package com.example.android.myshoecloset;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

/**
 * Created by man on 12/21/2017.
 */

public class Closet
{


    private static final String TAG = Closet.class.getSimpleName();

    //Brand name
    private final String brandName;
    //Shoe Name
    private final String shoeName;
    //Image of the shoe
    private final String shoeImage;


    public Closet(String brandName, String shoeName, String shoeImage)
    {
        this.brandName = brandName;
        this.shoeName  = shoeName;
        this.shoeImage = shoeImage;
    }

    public Closet(Cursor cursor)
    {
        this.brandName = null;
        this.shoeName = null;
        this.shoeImage = null;
    }

    public String getShoeImageName()
    {
        return shoeImage;
    }

    public String getBrandName()
    {
        return brandName;
    }

    public String getShoeName()
    {
        return shoeName;
    }

}
```

My Adapter Class(CustomAdapter.java)

```
package com.example.android.myshoecloset.data;
/*Assume appropriate imports*/

/**
 * Created by man on 11/23/2017.
 */

public class CustomAdapter  extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.TaskHolder> {

    private Cursor mCursor;
    private Context mContext;

    public static String shoeName;
    public static String brandName;
    public static byte[] byteArray;

    public CustomAdapter(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    public CustomAdapter()
    {
        mContext = null;
    }





    /* ViewHolder for each task item */
    public class TaskHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public TextView shoeBrandName;
        public TextView shoeName;
        public ImageView shoeImage;
        public LinearLayout linearLayout;

        public TaskHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            shoeBrandName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textBrandName);
            shoeImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.shoeImage);
            shoeName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textShoeName);
            linearLayout = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.linear_closet);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), ShoeDetailActivity.class);
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            v.getContext().startActivity(i);
        }


    }

    @Override
    public TaskHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        View itemView = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.text_row_item, parent, false);
        return new TaskHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(TaskHolder holder, int position) {


        int idIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.ShoeColumns._ID);
        int imgValue = mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.ShoeColumns.SHOE_IMAGE);
        int shoeBrandName = mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.ShoeColumns.SHOE_BRAND);
        int shoeName = mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.ShoeColumns.SHOE_NAME);

        mCursor.moveToPosition(position);



        final int id = mCursor.getInt(idIndex);
        byte[] shoeImg = mCursor.getBlob(imgValue);
        String brandNameStr = mCursor.getString(shoeBrandName);
        String shoeNameStr = mCursor.getString(shoeName);

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(shoeImg, 0, shoeImg.length);

        holder.itemView.setTag(id);
        holder.shoeImage.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 100, 100, false));
        holder.shoeBrandName.setText(brandNameStr);
        holder.shoeName.setText(shoeNameStr);

        holder.getAdapterPosition();


        CustomAdapter.shoeName = shoeNameStr;
        CustomAdapter.brandName = brandNameStr;
        CustomAdapter.byteArray = mCursor.getBlob(imgValue);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (mCursor != null) ? mCursor.getCount() : 0;
    }


    public void swapCursor(Cursor cursor) {
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.close();
        }
        mCursor = cursor;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

My ClosetFragment, which loads the information on a Loader and to the fragments recyclerview.

```
package com.example.android.myshoecloset;

/*Assume appropriate imports*/

public class ClosetFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    private static final String TAG = "ClosetFragment";

    protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    protected CustomAdapter mAdapter;
    private static final int CUSTOM_LOADER_ID = 0;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_closet, container, false);
        rootView.setTag(TAG);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));

        mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(CUSTOM_LOADER_ID, null, this);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(CUSTOM_LOADER_ID, null, this);    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, final Bundle loaderArgs) {
                return new AsyncTaskLoader<Cursor>(getActivity().getApplicationContext()) {
            Cursor mTaskData = null;

            @Override
            protected void onStartLoading()
            {
                if(mTaskData != null)
                {
                    deliverResult(mTaskData);
                }
                else
                {
                    forceLoad();
                }
            }

            public Cursor loadInBackground()
            {
                try
                {
                    return getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(DatabaseContract.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null,
                            null);

                } catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("", "Failed to asynchronously load data.");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }

            public void deliverResult(Cursor data)
            {
                mTaskData = data;
                super.deliverResult(data);
            }
        };
    }


    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data)
    {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }
    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader)
    {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

}
```

Finally here is my DetailsActivity(when the recyclerview item is clicked this is where the click will take you)

```
package com.example.android.myshoecloset;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.android.myshoecloset.data.CustomAdapter;

public class ShoeDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shoe_detail);

        ImageView imgShoe = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.shoeImgDetails);
        TextView  brandShoe = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.shoeBrandDetails);
        TextView  nameShoe  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.shoeNameDetails);
        byte[] b = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("ImageBit");
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
        imgShoe.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        brandShoe.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ShoeName"));
        nameShoe.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("BrandName"));
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: In the detail activity, I see a lot of calls to `getIntent().getXyzExtra()`, but in your `TaskHolder.onClick()` I don't see you adding any extras to the intent. Did you omit some code?

Comment: Well that was my problem was getting the data to be passed to that DetailsActivity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the relevant pieces of your code are the `onClick` method in your view holder:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), ShoeDetailActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    v.getContext().startActivity(i);
}
```

And the `onCreate` method in your details activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...
    byte[] b = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("ImageBit");
    ...
    brandShoe.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("ShoeName"));
    nameShoe.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("BrandName"));
}
```

In the details activity, you're trying to pull information out of the intent extras... but you've never provided that information in the first place. Making this information available to your view holder will require re-thinking how you've implemented the view holder itself.

I believe you should be able to use the viewholder's "adapter position" to get the necessary info out of your cursor at click time. Maybe something like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int position = getAdapterPosition();
    mCursor.moveToPosition(position);

    Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), ShoeDetailActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    int imgValue = mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.ShoeColumns.SHOE_IMAGE);
    int shoeBrandName = mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.ShoeColumns.SHOE_BRAND);
    int shoeName = mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.ShoeColumns.SHOE_NAME);

    i.putExtra("ImageBit", mCursor.getBlob(imgValue));
    i.putExtra("ShoeName", mCursor.getString(shoeBrandName));
    i.putExtra("BrandName", mCursor.getString(shoeName));

    v.getContext().startActivity(i);
}
```

(Note that `"ShoeName"` and `"BrandName"` appear to be swapped, but they're also swapped in your details activity so I left them that way.)

If this `getAdapterPosition()` + `mCursor` method doesn't work for you, you can always pass the necessary information to the view holder at bind time, and update the `onClick()` method when binding.

Let me know if this works for you. If it doesn't, we can try to figure it out from here.

Comment: YOU ARE A MAGICIAN! Thanks a lot Ben